# Как не дать добавить значение?

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть БД, в ней есть таблица запись, в самой таблице, есть колонка "Время"
Как мне сделать, чтобы нельзя было добавить одитнаковое время. Я пытался делать так:

```
string vremya = comboBox2.Text + ":" + comboBox3.Text;
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand dataCommand3 = new MySqlCommand();
dataCommand3.Connection = connection;
dataCommand3.CommandText = ("SELECT Время from Запись");
string temp = Convert.ToString(dataCommand3.ExecuteScalar());  
if (temp == vremya)
{
MessageBox.Show("Такое время уже занято!");
}
else 
{
MessageBox.Show("Добавлено!");
}
```

Но он сразу переходит к else, может нужно конкретней запрос делать? Или я чет не понимаю :3

Comment: При создании таблицы, присвоить этому полю свойство UNIQUE

Comment: @NewView А есть другой способ?

Comment: Есть, но он по любому не правильный по сравнению с предложенным :) Выборку можно делать по этому полю.. но это какие-то грабли превязанные к велосипеду :)

Comment: И селектор тогда надо менять, что типа `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE time_field = <you variable>`

Comment: P.S. это регистрация у зубного врача? :) суть и назначение кода? Попробуйте изменить поле в базе на UNIQUE, или сделать его индексом, дополнительным..

Answer (score 2):

Сделать поле в БД уникальным.

```
ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD UNIQUE (columnName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался
Сделал другой запрос:

```
string vremya = comboBox2.Text + ":" + comboBox3.Text;
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand dataCommand3 = new MySqlCommand();
dataCommand3.Connection = connection;
dataCommand3.CommandText = ("SELECT Время FROM `Запись` WHERE Время='" + vremya + "'");
string temp = Convert.ToString(dataCommand3.ExecuteScalar());
connection.Close();
```

Весь код выглядит так

```
string vremya = comboBox2.Text + ":" + comboBox3.Text;
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand dataCommand3 = new MySqlCommand();
dataCommand3.Connection = connection;
dataCommand3.CommandText = ("SELECT Время FROM `Запись` WHERE Время='" + vremya + "'");
string temp = Convert.ToString(dataCommand3.ExecuteScalar());
                connection.Close();
if (temp == vremya)
{
MessageBox.Show("Такое время уже занято!");
}
else {}
```

Comment: Лучше использовать INSERT  IGNORE (предварительно, как уже советовали умные люди, сделав поле уникальным). Он попытается вставить запись, и если не сумел этого сделать (mysqli_affwcted_rows() == 0) - тогда огорчайте юзера.

Comment: Конструкция вида `SELECT COUNT(*) ..` возвращает количество записей подпадающих под условие, вернеться int, так намного проще, если 0, значит свободно, и не надо мучиться со строками.